# Use shortcode in WordPress contact form 7 Success Message

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode, contact-form-7

I'm trying to use CF7 for an event registration along with the Nice PayPal Lite plugin which simply creates a paypal button with a set amount to redirect users to paypal upon click.  I would like to use the shortcode in the "success message" of CF7 so that after the user submits the form the paypal button appears and so instead of saying "Your message was sent successfully" I can add "Please click the paypal button below to complete your registration".  The problem is that the shortcode doesn't work when I put it the successful message field and just shows up as if it was normal text.

This is what the shortcode looks like: [nicepaypallite name="Coffee Mug" amount="12.50"]

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to link the Submit button to the PayPal URL.

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't exactly the best solution but it did the trick.